# Not sure how to do this while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
public static void decodeThis(BufferedImage im, String outputFile)
throws FileNotFoundException{
  int w = im.getWidth();
  int h=im.getHeight();
  int[] arr=im.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);
  int[] eightBit=new int[8];
  int counter=0;
  String[] aString=new String[arr.length];
  PrintStream out=new PrintStream(new File(outputFile));
  double value=0;
  int intVal=0;
  while (counter<arr.length){
    for (int j=0;j<eightBit.length;j++){
        eightBit[j] = arr[j+counter] & 1; //Extracts least significant bit, puts into eightBit array.
    }
    value=0;
    for (int x=0;x<eightBit.length;x++){
        value+=eightBit[x]*(Math.pow(2,x));
    }
    intVal=(int)value;
    out.print((char)intVal);
    counter=counter+8;
}
```

}

What I want to do is read, extract, and convert into a character 8 bits from arr while there are still pixels left to read in arr. For some reason when I run the commented for loop, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you paste the exception too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while(counter<arr.length)` loop runs `counter` to the length of `arr`, and the inner loop accesses `arr` using `j+counter`; that's guaranteed to run off the end of `arr` if `arr` is not an exact multiple of 8.

And since `arr` is the number of bits in the image, it's highly unlikely to be an exact multiple of 8.

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop condition.

```
while (counter <= arr.length - 8)
```